# Undefined Reference Error on compiling when Integrating New Custom G-Codes into Marlin 2.1

Tags: marlin, firmware

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to add new custom G-codes to Marlin 2.1.* firmware. Specifically, I'm aiming to introduce G-codes `M9910` to `M9919` into the firmware. While my implementation method has worked in Marlin 2.0, I'm facing difficulties integrating it into Marlin 2.1.

Here's the approach I've taken:

1. Configuration_adv.h:

```
#define New_Custom_Gcodes
```

2. gcode.cpp:

```
// Inside GcodeSuite::process_parsed_command()
switch (parser.command_letter) {
    ....
    case 'M':
        switch (parser.codenum) {
            // Existing cases...
            #if ENABLED(New_Custom_Gcodes)
                case 9910:
                case 9911:
                case 9912:
                case 9913:
                case 9914:
                case 9915:
                case 9916:
                case 9917:
                case 9918:
                case 9919:
                    M9910_M9919(); // Define/execute G-code macro
                    break;
            #endif
            // Existing cases...
        }
    // Rest of the function...
}
```

3. gcode.h:

```
class GcodeSuite {
public:
    // Existing codes...
    #if ENABLED(New_Custom_Gcodes)
        static void M9910_M9919();
    #endif
};
```

4. I've created a new file named M9910_M9919.cpp under Marlin\src\gcode\control, M9910_M9919.cpp:

```
#include "../../inc/MarlinConfig.h"

#if ENABLED(New_Custom_Gcodes)

#include "../gcode.h"
#include "../queue.h"
#include "../parser.h"

void GcodeSuite::M9910_M9919() {
    // Execute Custom G-codes
    switch (parser.codenum - 9910) {
        case 0:
            // Do something
            break;
        case 1:
            // Do something
            break;
        // Cases for M9911, M9912, ..., M9919
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#endif
```

Despite these steps, I'm encountering the following error during the linking stage:

```
c:/users/****/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: .pio/build/STM32H723ZE_btt/src/src/gcode/gcode.cpp.o: in function `GcodeSuite::process_parsed_command(bool)':
C:\Users\***\***\***\***\Marlin-bugfix-2.1.x/Marlin\src\gcode/gcode.cpp:1123: undefined reference to `GcodeSuite::M9910_M9919()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that this error suggests that the linker cannot find a reference to the M9910_M9919 function, indicating a problem with its definition or how it's being referenced, however I couldn't find what is the mistake in this case.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue. If there's anything I've overlooked or if there are specific changes in Marlin 2.1.* that may affect how custom G-codes are integrated, please let me know.